# Can we decrypt data, Language independently?

Tags: php, ruby, encryption

Can we decrypt data that is encrypted using another language. For example : TO decrypt data in PHP (.php), and data encrypted using ruby on rails.(.rb). Please suggest me.

Comment: [Yes](http://homepages.tesco.net/~J.deBoynePollard/FGA/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the encryption.

But for many types of encryption (and the accompanying decryption algorithms) there's libraries in many languages. After all an encryption algorithm is nothing but a mathematical function to mangle (and unmangle) data.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you have to use the same encryption method in both languages to be on the safe side. For example, use DES or AES implementations for both languages.

Comment: Not just "to be on the safe side."  If you don't use the same encryption algorithm, it won't work. Period.

Answer (score -1):

This is as if you asked whether one person can read a message written by another person.

Generally, if both persons use the same language (in your case, the same encryption method and the same set of keys), they should understand each other.